# How to compile a C code that uses GNU C extensions

Tags: c

I want to use the function `__sync_lock_test_and_set` which is not available in ANSI c, but is an GNU C extension.

When compile a piece of code which uses this extension, I get the following error,

```
/tmp/cc7Iat9G.o: In function `main':
swap.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `__sync_lock_test_set'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, what header file should I include, or what compiler flags should I give to compile a code with GNU C extensions

Comment: C11 has native atomics support. Use a modern C compiler and you can do this in standard C.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but could it be that __sync_lock_test_and_set takes a ptr to a volatile int? Or somehow you are passing the wrong parameters?

Comment: I am constrained to icpc (Intel Compiler) for my project. So, how do I compile this in icpc

Comment: Post the code/gcc invocation: that call is not related to any library and it should be swapped on the fly with a proper assembly routine

Comment: @Karthik I do not understand: are you using GCC intrinsics under the Intel compiler ?

Comment: I think you should change this question to be "How can I rewrite this GNU C so it works with icpc?" Only GCC fully supports GNU C extensions, and other compilers cannot be expected to work (although some of the more popular GNUisms may be duplicated elsewhere).

Comment: @ziu These particular atomic memory extensions are part of the  Intel Itanium Processor-specific Application Binary Interface and has been implemented by GCC. So, I naturally assumed they would have been implemented in icpc.

Comment: Forget about icpc. How do I compile the code under GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you typed `__sync_lock_test_set` when you meant `__sync_lock_test_and_set`. The latter is mentioned in the [GCC documentation on atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html%20GCC%20documentation%20on%20atomic%20builtins); the former is not.

Comment: So stupid of me. Surprised you were able to figure out my mistake. Thanks a lot.